# How to make sure that there will be no repeats in mt_rand() function?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

In my php web application I am storing every number generated by mt_rand() to the database and using mysql to check if it already exists, if it does then the index.php refreshes to get another number and then it again checks if the number exists, if it doesn't then the current number is stored in db orelse refresh.
"The problem is that there are chances where the stored numbers are generated again and again and page refreshes for a lot of time which can affect website loading time.
So Can you suggest more easy method ?

Comment: dump the data once in an array and then generate the number and compare with the array, in that case you have to go to db once only so it'll be fast I think.

Comment: Isn't that what DBs provide auto-increments for? Generating unique numbers? `mt_rand()` is a tool to provide random numbers, not to provide unique numbers.

Comment: Yeah I get your point, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

One way of storing distinct numbers in the database (table) is to store them in sequential order.

Initially, the table will be empty, so you can insert 1 in the table. Now, from the next time you just have to fetch the number stored in the last row. Increment the fetched number by 1 and then insert the incremented number in the table.

This way you can store distinct numbers in the database. Since every time only 3 database queries are running (first to get size of the table, second to get the number in the last row and third to insert the new number), this method will be comparatively fast.